# Python import from module variable

Tags: python, import

I have a package that contains a module with compatible imports. However, I cannot import from the exposed modules directly; I have to use slightly more inconvenient workarounds.

Inside common/compat.py, I have this:

```
import bcrypt
```

In main.py, this does not work:

```
from common.compat.bcrypt import hashpw
```

with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from common.compat.bcrypt import hashpw
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

However, this works fine:

```
from common.compat import bcrypt
# now bcrypt.hashpw works fine
```

Is there any way to make the first one work properly without having to do the second solution? I would prefer from imports for quite a few classes and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `bcrypt` is not actually a submodule of `common.compat`; the module object is actually a member attribute of the `common.compat` module object with the name `bcrypt` within `common.compat`'s namespace.  As a consequence, if you want to be able to import `bcrypt` as if it is a submodule of `common.compat` as opposed to a value from its namespace, you need to monkey around a bit.  You could create a dummy `bcrypt` module within your package structure then `from bcrypt import *` inside it to alias it, but probably the better way would be to directly modify `sys.modules` in `compat.py`.

```
import sys
import bcrypt

sys.modules['common.compat.bcrypt'] = bcrypt
```

As commenters have noted though, modifying `sys.modules` is dangerous.  I'm inferring from the fact that you call your package `common.compat` that you are creating some sort of compatibility module that implements fallback logic in case some dependency is not available.  Instead of hacking `sys.modules`, you'll likely be better served creating a `common.compat.crypto` module that looks something like

```
try:
    from bcrypt import hashpw
except ImportError:
    # Alternative import, hand-written alternative,
    # or function that raises NotImplementedError here
```

Then in your `main.py`, just `from common.compat.crypto import hashpw`.

Comment: Argh, don't give him ideas about modifying `sys.modules` like this! :) -- +1 for the correct explanation though.

Comment: Please put a big warning that messing with `sys.modules` is not a good idea, *especially* if the OP doesn't know what he's doing (which he doesn't since he asked this question).

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer and Bakuriu, better?

Answer (score 0):

Would the following be what you are looking for ?

```
from common.compat import bcrypt.hashpw
```

However, it seems a bad idea to build depedencies in such way, because you don't seem to need that compat.py even exist to get your bcrypt module. Thus I would rather do one of the following :

1. Import bcrypt.hashpw in main.py, as a direct dependency
2. Import bcrypt from the common/compat.py script like you suggest in your last snippet
3. Do something with hashpw in common/compat.py (e.g. subclassing or wrapping), and import the subclass/wrapper from compat.py in main.py